# Are you at increased risk of complications when receiving a vaccine shot/booster after you have had a symptomatic infection of Covid?

Tags: covid-19, research

Someone has told me that there is a study/studies that exist that showed that getting a vaccine booster after having a symptomatic infection of covid, increases your risk for complications.

I have searched through google and found nothing. Does this study even exist....because I can not find it.

Comment: I suspect this is a common claim but "someone told me" doesn't cut it on this site. Can you edit your post and add a significant online person making this claim?

Comment: Doesn't cut it? I am literally posting the question to see if a the research exists or not. Are you saying I can't ask if a specific research exists?

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I recommend you ask the somebody who told you about those studies as to where they found them.  Then you can edit this question and add links to the studies. Generally speaking "I once heard..." isn't considered a notable claim.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the COVID-19 vaccines have worse side-effects for people who have already contracted COVID-19?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50476/do-the-covid-19-vaccines-have-worse-side-effects-for-people-who-have-already-con)

Answer (score 5):

The immune reaction [is higher for people who had been in contact with the virus](https://www.gavi.org/vaccineswork/why-vaccine-side-effects-might-be-more-common-people-whove-already-had-covid-19). But this is something expected:

> The most common symptoms they reported were fatigue (9%), headache
> (8%) and chills or shivers (4%), mostly during the first two days
> after receiving the vaccine. However, approximately a third of those
> who had previously had COVID-19 reported at least one mild, whole-body
> reaction within seven days, compared to 19% of those who hadn’t
> previously had COVID-19.
>
> People aged under 55 were more likely to experience such symptoms, and
> they were also more common when people received their second dose of
> vaccine. In most cases, these mild side effects were short-lived, with
> just 3% of people experiencing them beyond three days.

Comment: Not what I would call a "complication", though.